# Parsing a multiline file

Tags: java

Ive to parse a multiline file, structured as follows:

```
Name Surname
birthdate(int)
Name Surname
birthdate(int)
```

and so on. I opened the file, getting an ArrayList, and created a class which serves as a data structure, but i don't know how to parse each string, recognising if it is a number or a name. Can you help me?

Comment: the file contains exactly this or is just a representation?

Comment: That's just a representation. "Name", "surname" and "birthdate" stay for different names, surnames and birthdates.

Comment: Use regular expressions to check for matches, e.g. `birthdate(\d+)` should capture the number in a group (if the expression matches) and then you just parse it. Besides that it is _you_ who knows the structure of the file and thus _you_ have to come up with the parsing logic. As it is your question is very vague and hence it's hard to help.

Comment: @Thomas - his b-date is int value.

Comment: Please show the code

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is the main concern:

> i don't know how to parse each string, recognising if it is a number
>   or a name.

**Use `isNumeric()` function to see if you can parse value to number or leave it as a string**. Then parse it accordind to value the function returns.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {  
   try {  
      double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
   } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
      return false;  
   }  
   return true;  
}
```

...

```
//put data into ArrayList
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    String elem = data.get(i);
    boolean isNum = isNumeric(elem);
    if (isNum) {
       int val = Integer.parseInt(elem);
    } else {
       //do what you want with `elem`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to read your file

It has helper methods to read various types of input if you know the structure of input data (I assume you know its structure)

Here is a sample code to help you read it from some file with given structure

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

    while(s.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("First Name : " + s.next() + ", Last Name : " + s.next() + ", Age : " +s.nextInt());
    }
    s.close();
```

You can create a class with attributes firstName, lastName and age and assign above values to a new object and add that object in List.

Hope this helps.